# there is a way I can bind a flex property to a flash property?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm wondering if there is a way I can bind a flex property to flash property?, the flash property is inside a swc file created in flash with the Flex Component Kit for Flash Professional, I can manipulate the flash component as a regular flex component, but I want to bind their properties, is there a way?? thanks!!

Comment: `BindingUtils` is the way to go - post some code and we can try and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [BindingUtils methods](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_7.html) to accomplish this.  The linked documentation includes references to the LiveDocs for the BindingUtils class and some simple samples.